# sql case when col is not blank

Tags: mysql, null, case-when

i asked a similiar question earlier, went back and revisited my logic. Here's an update. I'm in teamsql running mysql.

I want to limit the case when to when a col (lc.ladder_advocacy) is not blank.

```
SELECT 
@row_number:=(CASE
    WHEN @member_id = lh.member_id and lc.ladder_advocacy IS NOT NULL 
THEN @row_number + 1
    ELSE 1
END) AS rank,
@member_id:=lh.member_id AS member_id,
lc.name,
lh.trigger_event_date,
lc.ladder_advocacy 
FROM
leenk_ladder_history AS lh
LEFT JOIN leeds_so.leenk_ladder_config AS lc ON lh.ladder_config_id = lc.id
WHERE
ladder_change = 1 AND trigger_active = 1 
ORDER BY member_id , trigger_event_date DESC;
```

I've also tried:

```
lc.ladder_advocacy <> ``
lc.ladder_advocacy <> ""
lc.ladder_advocacy != ""
lc.ladder_advocacy != ``
```

Still getting a return with the lc.ladder_advocacy col showing blank values.

[image: LADDER_ADVOCACY still showing nulls]

Any thoughts?

Comment: By "blank" do you mean "could be a bunch of spaces"? Is it possible those values are actually `NULL`?

Comment: If you don't want those rows included in the results at all, you need to filter them out in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: @tadman I tried the null option -- natta

Comment: @barmar I tried that too - they're still showing up

Comment: It would help if you could give an example that reproduces this problem more precisely. This is why screenshots are really frustrating. We can't tell if that's five spaces, two spaces, a non-breaking space, or some invisible character. We can if you paste in text.

Comment: @tadman ok! when I copy / paste the cell, there is nothing (no spaces, anything). It is the last col below. Does that help? 

rank,member_id,name,trigger_event_date,ladder_advocacy
1,0031W00001yQ1tJQAS,LEE Regional Training,2018-01-01,

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the beautify feature in teamsql added an extra space.

answer:

```
SELECT 
@row_number:=(CASE
    WHEN @member_id = lh.member_id
    THEN @row_number + 1
    ELSE 1
END) AS rank,
@member_id:=lh.member_id AS member_id,
lc.name,
lh.trigger_event_date,
lc.ladder_advocacy 
FROM
leeds.leenk_ladder_history AS lh
    LEFT JOIN leeds_so.leenk_ladder_config AS lc ON lh.ladder_config_id = lc.id
WHERE
    ladder_change = 1 AND trigger_active = 1 and lc.ladder_advocacy <> '' 
ORDER BY member_id , trigger_event_date DESC;
```